# I have a string that contains an Arabic character, I want the character to be in the middle of the string but it keeps putting it at the end

Tags: javascript, string, arabic

I need to put a string in my frontend that contains two numbers and an Arabic character, these numbers should have the Arabic character in the middle, i tried some different methods to do this, but they all put the Arabic character at the end of the string;

I tried this as a solution but it is still not working, can you guys help me out with this?

```js
let s = "10-م-20";
let parts = s.split("-");
let new_parts = [parts[0], "م", parts[2]];
let new_s = new_parts.join("-");
console.log(new_s);  // Output was: "10-م-20"
```

Comment: But your input does not have an Arabic character in the middle, can you explain? Besides Arabic being an RTL language, are you talking about the character being in the middle when RTL mode?

Comment: Should it be let new_parts = [parts[0], "م", parts[1]];?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING](https://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Terminating_Explicit_Directional_Embeddings_and_Overrides), which is where you prepend the string with `\u202A` like so:

```js
let s = "10-م-20";
let parts = s.split("-");
let new_parts = ["\u202A" + parts[0], "\u202A" + "م", "\u202A" + parts[2]];
let new_s = new_parts.join("-");
console.log(new_s);
```

Outputs

> // 10-‪م-‪20

Note: you can replace the hardcoded م with `parts[1]` if desired:

```
let new_parts = ["\u202A" + parts[0], "\u202A" + parts[1], "\u202A" + parts[2]];
```

If you simply need to create the string `10-‪م-‪20` then you can simplify it to this, without any splitting or joining:

```js
console.log("10-\u202Aم-\u202A20")
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this is the solution i have been searching for!